# "Would" in answers

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "would" in my answer if it is in a question?
"Would you want to be  a politician/a famous person?"

"No, I wouldn't want to be a politician."

Comment: It is always safe to, yes. But you don't have to. "Would you want to be famous?" "Not really." If you are asked, "Would you like a coffee?", "Yes, please" is fine. Often  the word "would" is elided and the stress falls on the next word: "I'd LOVE one." "No, I'd HATE to be a politician." A request - "Would you pass me the pliers?" - obviously doesn't need much of a reply.

Comment: Can I just say "yes" or "no"?

Comment: You can if it's the pliers!

Comment: I mean when talking about becoming famous.

Comment: Would you like to be famous? Would you want to meet a famous person? Yes, I would live to. No, not really. Or just "yes." "No".

Comment: Well, you can, bit it's a bit curt. Not very communicative, or friendly. It would be considered **bad manners** when offered a coffee. About being famous it might just seem a bit recalcitrant.

Comment: I see no good reason why the questioner should ask ***Would** you want to be a politician/a famous person?* in the first place, as opposed to straightforward ***Do** you want to be...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: One reason might be that the questioner and a friend are watching a politician or famous person on TV. I imagined it stressed 'would YOU want to be a...'

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: Good point (snap! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact wording you use is sometimes used for more hypothetical questions if it is less likely that the person would ever do that thing. E.g. when you "would you (ever) want to be a politician?", you are implying that it's unlikely to happen, and you are asking if the person likes the idea in principle.

If it might be a genuine ambition or realistic goal of the person, you might say "would you like to be a politician?" Or more direct "do you want to be a politician?"